# Как синхронно загрузить статику в nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Пытаюсь загрузить статику для nuxt приложения. Есть файл `shakal.js` и в `nuxt.config` подключается он вот так `{ src: '/shakal.js', async: true, defer: true, body: true },`. Проблема возникает проблема при загрузке плагинов, конкретно здесь `everCookie = new window['evercookie'](options)`.
Проблема в ошибке, что пишет не определен `window.evercookie`, который как раз инициализируется в `shakal.js`. Можно ли дождаться загрузки `shakal.js`, перед загрузкой плагинов?

Answer (score 0):

1) Помести то что хочешь загрузить до всего в `<head></head>`, если оно ничего не выполняет с узлами или событиями.

2) Если хочешь загрузить/выполнить в момент формирования узлов, то размещай скрипт/ты сразу поле блока с узлами с которым будешь работать.

3) Повесить слушатель событий на момент полной загрузки страницы

PS
*узлы - это теги которые ты хочешь менять или что-то в них творить